# how to load a unstructured data format in hive or mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, hive, hbase

I have a data which is not a valid json or csv but it has a fixed format as below

my data format :

```
{
    1=1568243607
    4=0
    7=2
    8=
    9=
    517=0
    519=AAA_PRE
    1250=1,
    1346=612376722611,76,-917170#13933614,1,-69#623599168091,157
    8888=in4_G_008_380219_20190912054326_6.s.2019091205
    9999=20190912
}

{
    3=1568243609
    4=0
    7=2
    8=
    8888=in4_G_008_380219_20190912054326_6.s.2019091205
    9999=20190912
}

{
    1=1568243608
    4=0
    3=2
    8=
    9=
    14=99
    16=1
    18=0
 }
```

now I need to load this type of data in hive or mongodb  or hbase the thing is we don't get fixed number of columns it will vary from one record to other record.

can anyone help me with this

Comment: From where you are getting this type of data? What is the data type?
 `MongoDB` store data as a document in `JSON` format. For your problem statement at least you need to convert this data in a valid JSON form so that MongoDB allows you to store it in a collection.

Comment: hi  @A.Todkar  I have used Apache nifi to convert into valid json and stored into hive (all data types are string only ) it is working fine but We get around 600GB data per day which  is taking  huge time so we are looking for a alternative which can store above format data .
NOTE:- data format is fixed as we get from vendor